# typedef template without template rebind. Use as a template of template class parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I want to do something like this:

```
template<class T>
class BaseSubscriber {};

template<class T>
class BasePublisher
{
    // not working : invalid use of template-name 'BaseSubscriber' without an argument list
    typedef BaseSubscriber SubscriberType;

    // compiling
    typedef BaseSubscriber<T> SubscriberTypeT;
};


template< template<class T> class Subscriber, class Data >
class ClassA:
    public Subscriber<Data> 
{
};

template< template<class T> class Publisher, class Data >
class ClassB:
    public Publisher<Data>  
{
    // Ok, but I want that the type "BaseSubscriber" depends on the template parameter Publisher
    void method1(ClassA<BaseSubscriber, Data>&);


    // I want something like that. But how to define SubscriberType ?
    void method2(ClassA<Publisher<Data>::SubscriberType, Data>&);
    // or (SubscriberType only depends on the Publisher, nor on the Data)
    void method2(ClassA<Publisher::SubscriberType, Data>&);


    // Error : template argument is invalid
    void method3(ClassA<Publisher::SubscriberTypeT, Data>&);
};
```

Is it possible to define some `SubscriberType` that I can use for `classA` template parameter? Or is there any work around?

If possible I'd like to keep the `classA` prototype. I don't want to change it in

```
template<class TSubscriber > classA {};
```

And I can't use C++11.
Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit confusing what you mean when you say:

```
// I want something like that. But how to define SubscriberType ?
void method2(ClassA<Publisher::SubscriberType>);
```

As `Publisher` is a template yet you're not passing it any arguments.

Anyway, here are some options:

In C++11 you can use template aliases:

```
template<class T>
class BasePublisher
{
    template<typename U>
    using SubscriberType = BaseSubscriber<U>;
};
```

You can also use nested classes:

```
template<class T>
class BaseSubscriber {};

template<class T>
class BasePublisher
{
    template<class U>
    class BaseSubscriber {};
};
```

Or change `ClassA` to use a `type` member:

```
template<class T>
class BasePublisher
{
    template<class U>
    struct SubscriberType {
        typedef BaseSubscriber<U> type;
    };
};

template< template<class T> class SubscriberT >
class ClassA {
    typedef typename SubscriberT::type Subscriber;
};
```

Or sometimes inheritance works if you don't need an alias:

```
template<class T>
class BasePublisher
{
    template<class U>
    struct SubscriberType : BaseSubscriber<U> {};
};
```

Comment: How can I use the nested class Toto `template<class T> class BasePublisher { template<class U> class Toto{}; };` in my classB ? `method1(classA<Publisher<Data>::Toto, Data>&)` doesn't work. Is it possible without C++11 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Template aliases are not allowed in C++03 although they are in C++11.

Is your goal is to be able to do:

```
typename BaseSubscriber<A>::SubscriberType<B>
```

in C++03 you should use a nested class thus:

```
template< typename T > struct BasePublisher
{
   template< typename U > struct Subscriber
   {
       typedef BaseSubcriber<U> type;
   };
};
```

and now you can possibly do typename BasePublisher::Subscriber::type;

In C++11 the syntax would be:

```
template < typename T > struct BasePublisher
{
   template< typename U > using SubscriberType = BaseSubscriber<U>;
};
```

there are not many compilers that support that yet.
although as you can't do typename typename it might need another typedef in between.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly you want `ClassA` to get an instantiation of `BaseSubscriber`, for example `BaseSubscriber<my_tag>` and `ClassB` on an instantiation of `BasePublisher`. is it correct?

If your answer is yes, then why you declare `template` argument of `ClassA` and `ClassB` as template, you don't want to do something with it in `ClassA` or `ClassB`, so it should be a class not a templated class:

```
template<class T>
class BasePublisher
{
    // compiling
    typedef BaseSubscriber<T> SubscriberTypeT;
};
template< class SubscriberT > class ClassA : SubscriberT {};
template< class PublisherT >
class ClassB : PublisherT {
    void method1( ClassA<typename PublisherT::SubscriberTypeT> );
};
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I simplified the problem too much. I edit my post to show why I need a template argument of class A as template.

Comment: OK! But in your edited version you don't need template argument either!! All I say is if your version of `ClassA` depend on special instantiation of it argument so why you take it as template??

Comment: You're right. But I really need that class A depends on a template Subscriber type, not on an instanciation of this type.  In fact classA works on a typelist (Data is the Typelist). And I need to specify `ClassA` like this     `template<Subscriber, Head, Tail> ClassA<Subscriber, class Typelist<Head, Tail> > :     Subscriber<Head>,     ClassA<Subscriber, Tail>{}`. I need that ClassA inherit on an other ClassA which have the same Subscriber template type but with an other instanciation of this template type (the second ClassA will inherit on `Subscriber<Tail>`).